# How to reuse a memory block previously allocated to a vector in c++

Tags: c++, c++11, memory-management, boost, boost-pool

I have multiple vectors of structure objects for different structures. Now I want to reuse the same memory for all the vector objects.i.e,Once my work is done with one vector i want to erase its elements from the memory and assign that memory to the other vector. 
i.e.The first vector is of one structure type object and the second vector is  a structure type object of a completely different structure.
I am using windows 8.1 64-bit.

Comment: You would need a memory pool with custom allocator.

Comment: @NickyC Can you give  some examples of how to create a memory pool with a custom allocator.

Comment: `vector` would automatic reallocate it's internal memory. Are you sure it never happened?

Comment: @appleapple When did I say that?? I am just asking how to create a memory pool with custom allocator...

Comment: every time it reallocate, it is unlikely to use same storage, you probably need more clarification of what you want in question.

Comment: @RParthiban I can't. I only conceptually know what to do. I don't know how to implement it.

Answer (score 2):

When you erase vector elements, the memory allocated for the vector elements is not freed until you call `std::vector::shrink_to_fit`. Thus you do not have to do special actions to reuse the allocated memory.

It is not clean what you mean under

> Once my work is done with one vector i want to erase its elements from
>   the memory and assign that memory to the other vector.

You could continue using the same vector with the same memory, or you can call `v1.swap(v2)` to exchange allocated memories of two vectors, or you can move allocated memory of one vector to another `v2 = std::move(v1)`.

It is applicable to vectors containing elements of a same type or pointers, that is not suitable to your case.

Comment: No, the vectors are of structure type so i can't perform a  swap operation on vectors belonging to two different structures.                                         
  "Once my work is done with one vector i want to erase its elements from the memory and assign that memory to the other vector."                                   The first vector is of one structure type object and the second vector is  a structure type object of a completely different structure.

Comment: Even `std::vector::shrink_to_fit` doesn't guaranty to free memory :-/

Answer (score 0):

Being able to move allocated memory from a vector of one type to a vector containing another is not a feature supported by `std::vector`. I would suggest writing/finding another container that fits your needs.